# JSF2.0 and JSTL's <c:set> tag with map?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl

I am trying below things

**1- Not Working**

```
<c:set var="key" value="#{outputType}" >

<h:outputText value="#{outputType}"></h:outputText>
</c:set>
```

**2- Not Working**

```
<c:set var="key" value="#{outputType}" >
</c:set>
<h:outputText value="#{bean.stitchingEnumMap[key]}" />
```

**3- But this is working**

```
 <h:outputText value="#{outputType}"></h:outputText>
```

My problem i have to get the value from a MAP `stitchingEnumMap` and for this key i am getting from  `<c:set/>` tag.

FYI output variable i am passing from another JSF page like this

```
<ui:include src="../templates/comePage.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="bean" value="#{beanName}" />
        <ui:param name="property" value="outputType" />
        <ui:param name="outputType" value="#{record[property]}" />

</ui:include>
```

**EDIT :-**

How to access value of MAP ? I am trying something like below

```
<c:set var="key" value="#{outputType}" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.stitchingEnumMap['#{key}']}" />
```

If this is not right way what other option can be available to access value from map?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense is a duplicate!... (and 1 is not intended to work...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Why are you even trying it in a 'complex' way like this... Why not 'just' `<h:outputText value="#{bean.stitchingEnumMap[outputType]}" />` and why `<ui:param name="property" value="outputType" />
        <ui:param name="outputType" value="#{record[property]}" />` which is weird to.... Please get back to the basics of your problem. Looks like a x-y problem

Comment: Yes, and? You've asked many questions before, each time we ask you to clarify you do not clarfy, instead you add what looks like irrelevant info (you do not make it a [mcve])...  All we see are code snippets... Get back to your REAL PROBLEM/QUESTION

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks